# Why join another table that is not in the SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join

There's a filter in the WHERE clause. What's the purpose of it? I'm trying to understand the logic behind that. I don't see the need to even join table B if it's not even in the SELECT statement.

Example:

```
   Select 
   A.col1,
   A.col2,
   A.col3
   From table A
   Inner join Table B
   On A.A = B.B

   Where B.col = value
```

Comment: Pretty simple, it is to make sure you only pull rows from A that have a corresponding row in B. Think about a set of students, and you want to know all the students that took a specific test. You don't care about how they scored, just that they took the test, so the output doesn't need to include any of the columns from the test table.

Comment: You are *filtering* the records by doing an `INNER JOIN`.  If something does not satisfy the `JOIN` condition, it is filtered out of the results.  Additionally, you're only looking for things that match in `TableB` that have `col = value`.  If both of those conditions fail, the record is filtered out of the results.  The resulting records are only displaying their values from the `A` side.  Try replacing the `SELECT` with `SELECT *` and commenting out the `WHERE` and `JOIN`s to visually see what's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine you have two tables, Person and Company (Company the person is currently working in). You want to select all people that are working in the same company (let's say Google). Without joining Person to Company you will not be able to write that condition, as your condition refers to column from Company table.